# Apply codon translation function to all elements of data.frame

Tags: r, bioconductor

I have a data.frame that looks like

```
df <- data.frame(P1 = c("ATG","GTA","GGG","GGG"), P2 = c("TGG","GAT","GGG","GCG"))
```

I want to convert each DNA codon to an amino-acid using the below function (but any translate option is viable), and output an identical data.frame but with single letter amino-acids rather than codons:

```
library(Biostrings)
library(seqinr)
    translate_R <- function(x)
    {
      translate(s2c(as.character(x)))
    }
```

It works for individual elements of the data.frame

```
> translate_R(df[1,1])
[1] "M"
```

But trying to apply this to the whole data.frame isn't working. What am I missing? I don't understand why there is an error, as googling how to do this suggests it should work. Missing something fundamental I guess.

```
> df[] <- lapply(df, translate_R)

Error in seq.default(from = frame + 1, to = frame + l, by = 3) : 
  wrong sign in 'by' argument
In addition: Warning message:
In s2c(as.character(x)) :
 Error in seq.default(from = frame + 1, to = frame + l, by = 3) : 
  wrong sign in 'by' argument
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `translate_R` function is expecting a single value, but it's getting a vector.  You can fix this by passing in individual values.

In other words, iterate over columns of `df` with an outer `apply` and then over values in each column with an inner `apply`.

Here's how to do it with base R:

```r
data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) sapply(x, translate_R)))
```

And here's a tidyverse version with `map`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% mutate(across(everything(), ~map(., translate_R)))
```

In both cases, the output is:

```r
  P1 P2
1  M  W
2  V  D
3  G  G
4  G  A
```

Answer (score 0):

Another potential tidyverse solution is to use the ["rowwise"](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/rowwise.html) tidyverse function:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(Biostrings)
library(seqinr)

translate_R <- function(x) {
  translate(s2c(as.character(x)))
}

df <- data.frame(P1 = c("ATG","GTA","GGG","GGG"), P2 = c("TGG","GAT","GGG","GCG"))

df %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ translate_R(.x)))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#> # Rowwise: 
#>   P1    P2   
#>   <chr> <chr>
#> 1 M     W    
#> 2 V     D    
#> 3 G     G    
#> 4 G     A
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>